# How to open a program from a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want the following workflow:

1. A Browser opens and a person is for example login in (it is not important what the person does)
2. The Person is redirected to a new Page and another program should open

You may know this behaviour from zoom when you open a link to a meeting and zoom opens up. How is this accomplished? What do I need to tell the Browser?

Comment: You need to have a program install the right scheme/protocol action on the users computer. You cannot just arbitrarily run any program

Comment: A custom MIME type is what you’re looking for. If you want it to work for everybody you’ll have a lot of work but [here’s some info on registering a custom MIME type for Linux](https://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/linux/tux/mimetype)

Comment: For instance you could open a `mailto:` url in Outlook or Thunderbird, but that program must be listening.`

Answer (score -1):

You can handle it by ActiveXObject.
Ex) Opening a notepad program

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var program = "notepad.exe";
shell.Run(program, 1, true);
```